# Solvability of a quadratic congruence modulo $p^{k}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime number and let $a$ be an integer where $p$ and $a$ are relatively prime. If $k$ is a positive integer, prove that the congruence $x^{2} ≡_{p^{k}} a$ is solvable if and only if $x^{2} ≡_{p} a$ is solvable. In the case of solvability, prove that $x^{2} ≡_{p^{k}} a$ has exactly two incongruent solutions modulo $p^{k}$.

$\Rightarrow$: Let $x_{0}$ be a solution for $x^{2} ≡_{p^{k}} a$. Then we know $p^{k} | x_{0}^{2} - a$. So write $np^{k} = x_{0}^{2} - a$

$p|p^{k}$ since $p$ is obviously a divisor of $p^{k}$, so write $mp = p^{k}$. Combine the two:

$$np^{k}=x_{0}^{2} - a$$
$$\Rightarrow n(mp) = x_{0}^{2} - a$$
$$\Rightarrow (nm)p = x_{0}^{2} - a$$ and $nm$ is obviously an integer, so

$\Rightarrow x^{2} ≡_{p} a$ has solution $x_{0}$ as well. This shows that a solution for the congruence modulo $p^{k}$ must also be a solution for the congruence modulo $p$ (which itself has exactly two incongruent solutions, by a previously established theorem). So, speaking in modulo $p^{k}$, the congruence has two solutions either way.

It's $\Leftarrow$ that i'm having a problem with:
Let $x_{0}$ be a solution for $x^{2} ≡_{p} a$. Then $p|x_{0}^2 - a$; i.e., $np = x_{0}^{2} - a$ for some integer $n$. But this doesn't help a whole lot. What should I do from here? I think I've done something wrong, because $3|5^2 - 1$, but $3^2\nmid 5^2 - 1$ (just a quick example).

Comment: Hey @LonelyMathematician!  Your second and third paragraphs both have $\implies$ at the beginning.  =)

Comment: @JoseArnaldoDris, the second paragraph was just a statement that followed from a previous statement.

Comment: Do you know Hensel's lemma? That's the usual tool for establishing this.

Comment: I actually missed the class we talked about Hensel's lemma. I originally thought it would be used here, but upon looking it up online, it involves rings of polynomials over the reals and uses monic polynomials in the statement of the theorem. Since this course is strictly number theory and doesn't generalize to algebra, I brushed it off. I still don't really "get it" since it uses polynomials, so how do I apply it here?

Comment: Ohh I see. My bad!